# image randomization in Psychopy

Tags: psychopy

I am trying to make an experiment in Psychopy where I will project an image on the screen and will ask for a response from the tester. I would like for the images to come up randomly in a loop but after the tester has selected a response to the image I would like the next random image to come up with the original image not a part of the image bank. I would like to go through the entire set of stimuli and then end the test when the last image is projected.

How can I randomize a variable in a loop and then remove that specific stimuli from the entire set when the next cycle is started?

Comment: Are you using coder or builder? It is not clear what "the original image" is or what the "image bank" is since there "original image" apparently is not contained therein. Do you just mean that all images should be shown exactly once? In that case, just select 'random sequence' in the setting for the builder loop (it's the default) or in coder, just randomize your trial list and loop through it. If you want to run multiple such loops, wrap the inner loop in an outer loop.

Comment: I was able to complete the task with a simple loop. They were just jpg images. Now my next challenge is to figure out why they are formatted so weirdly during the experiment. Thank you!!